# Rails - comparing datetime stored as text to current datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my database I have a datetime stored as text as:

```
2013-12-14T02:35:00-07:00
```

I want to determine if this time is before the current time. I can do this in Ruby as follows:

```
if DateTime.parse('2013-12-14T02:35:00-07:00') < Time.now.to_datetime
  #do something
end
```

This provides the expected results. However, I am accessing my database like this:

```
@list = Alert.where("time_alert < ? ", Time.now.to_datetime)
```

which is not working as time_alert is being stored as text and the comparison is off. I am not sure how to parse time_alert into a DateTime object like in the condition.

Comment: you need to use your database specific commands to convert `time_alert` into a datetime type so that the query can resolve the date properly

Comment: consider changing your storage to datetime instead of text, you will continue to fight this going forward. Also you might want to use `Time.zone.now` instead of `Time.now` see http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/ for more on timezones and rails